# how to remove "#" from pressed link and alert the value of href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link

```
<a href='#test1'  >some_link</a>
```

When I press it I start some ajax manipulations with it.
Thing is when you press it it adds "#test1" to the address url in browser.

Now:

1. I want to remove "#" sign.
2. Alert the value of href also without "#" sign when I press the link.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
     window.history.pushState({state:'new'},'New State', href);
     //do your stuff
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Awesome with the pushState. Probably need to separate the href substring though, for browser compatibility. Also you should alert() it.

Comment: yep, great job! I did alert myself.  Jordan what's about browser compatibility ???

Comment: @Jordan: why I'd have to alert it?

Comment: That's it I'm sick of this compatibility :) I'll make some alert to user to update his browser. That does it. Too tired from this crossbrowsing wars

Comment: 1 more question . I have $(window).hashchange on this page. and return false of your script is blocking hashchange detection. Is there any way out of this problem ?

Comment: @genesis-φ the question asks you to alert it, although clearly he's just trying to get the actual substring so I'm sure your solution is fine.

Comment: @David the browser will silently fail on the pushState, and you have a variable containing the data you want, so this solution will work for you now that it's edited. No worries about browser compat with the latest edits.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('href').replace('#',''));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        alert($(this).attr('href').substring(1));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XqKBD/

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.location='\'" >
```

Try that....